# How to automatically create a Google Play app?

Tags: android, google-api, google-play, google-play-console, cicd

How do I create a new Google Play app in an automated scenario? I need it for a CI/CD pipeline which would create completely new apps on its own.

Comment: Afaik it is not possible to do this with the official Play API. You need to create apps manually.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? I never faced a limit when it comes to Google :'D

Comment: There is no official API to create app in google play.